# TFS Test Manager API - Getting a specific revision of a TestCase has zero Actions

Tags: testing, tfs, mtm

When trying to get an old revision, the following code has zero actions:

These 2 Interfaces are gotten beforehand appropriately:
    ITestManagementTeamProject testProject;
    ITestSuiteEntry testCase;

```
int testCaseRevision = testProject.TestResults
.ByTestId(testCase.Id)
.FirstOrDefault(p => p.TestRunId == testRunID).TestCaseRevision;

ITestCaseHelper helper = testProject.TestCases as ITestCaseHelper;
ITestCase testCaseProperRevision = helper.Find(testCase.Id, testCaseRevision);
```

**testCaseProperRevision.Actions** has zero Actions, but there should be 38.  How do I get the missing actions?

Thanks in advance for you help.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want to get the history of Test Case work item. You can check [this blog](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/shair/2013/10/30/tfs-api-part-52-getting-work-item-history/) on how to get Work Item revision list and display the Fields of specific revision:

Step 1: Connecting To TFS And Getting Work Item Store

```
private void btnConnect_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    TeamProjectPicker tpp = new TeamProjectPicker(TeamProjectPickerMode.NoProject, false);
    if (tpp.ShowDialog() != System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK || tpp.SelectedTeamProjectCollection == null)
    {
        btnFetch.IsEnabled = txtWitId.IsEnabled = false;
        return;
    }

    tfs = tpp.SelectedTeamProjectCollection;
    store = new WorkItemStore(tfs, WorkItemStoreFlags.BypassRules);
    btnFetch.IsEnabled = txtWitId.IsEnabled = true;
}
```

Step 2: Getting Work Item History

Using WorkItemStore object you can get the work item, the work item object contains a Revisions collection that will allow you to navigate inside the work item history.

```
<span class="kwrd">private</span> <span class="kwrd">void</span> FetchWorkItemHistory()
{
    <span class="kwrd">if</span> (<span class="kwrd">string</span>.IsNullOrEmpty(txtWitId.Text)) <span class="kwrd">return</span>;

    <span class="kwrd">if</span> (!<span class="kwrd">int</span>.TryParse(txtWitId.Text, <span class="kwrd">out</span> _workitemId)) <span class="kwrd">return</span>;

    WorkItem wit = store.GetWorkItem(_workitemId);
    listRevs.ItemsSource = wit.Revisions;
}
```

You can also get the Work Item from specific Revision:

```
WorkItem wit = store.GetWorkItem(_workitemId, rev.Index);
```

Answer (score 0):

It was a problem with the debugger in Visual Studio 2015, the Actions are there when I run the program without setting a breakpoint.